# How do I access array and subarrays on a JSON response from a REST service?

Tags: php, web-services

How do I parse all the content from a REST service response coming as JSON with PHP into an array and then how do I access the array items including subarrays?
As the example shows below, the are subarrays and I would need to access their items.

Example REST response:

```
Array ( [id] => 1234567890 [summary] => Array ( [workload] => Array ( [lang_english] => - flighthours, 74 h - flightpreparation, 42 h - flightplan, 3 h - flightsimulation, 62 h - flightexam, 4 h [lang_swedish] => [lang_german] => )
```

Comment: you want to access where in frontend or backend ?

Comment: Hi. In PHP. I need to use the array items to display a view for the user. So basically access the items and display the item as a web page view (html).